# Error when indexing with SolrJ

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, solrj

I am trying to index some data with Solr by using SolrJ. But I have this error that I can't solve.

```html
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/corename: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405  HTTP POST method is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/index.html. Reason:
<pre>    Error 405  HTTP POST method is not supported by this URL</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:558)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:259)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:85)
 at indexsolr.index(indexsolr.java:33)
 at LoadData.toIndex(LoadData.java:102)
 at LoadData.loadDocuments(LoadData.java:72)
 at IndexLaunch.main(IndexLaunch.java:12)
```

This is how I connect (I am in local)

```js
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/corename").build();
```

When I remove the "#" It throws a NullPointerException. I really can get why I have these errors. Please find the errors below:

```js
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/corename: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.mapValueClassesToFieldType(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:509)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:396)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:75)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:98)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:188)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:144)
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:311)
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:130)
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:276)
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
 at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:178)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:195)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:108)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:55)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:382)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:326)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:590)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:259)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:85)
 at indexsolr.index(indexsolr.java:33)
 at LoadData.toIndex(LoadData.java:102)
 at LoadData.loadDocuments(LoadData.java:72)
 at IndexLaunch.main(IndexLaunch.java:12)
```

I have been struggling for a week with this indexing...

Comment: The # shouldn't be there. What is causing the NPE?

Comment: Follow this instruction: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/using-solrj.html#indexing-in-solrj

Comment: @CliffWillsher here is the error I get when I remove # (please check the post, I edited it)

Comment: @HolgerThurow Okay I will check

Comment: It's clearly trying to update. Check that the version of SolrJ is the same as, or very close to the version of the Solr server. SolrJ uses a binary format to exchange data and the format sometimes changes between versions.

Answer (score 1):

As Cliff hints to, the `#` part of the URL is a local anchor (only interpreted by the browser), and should not be part of the URL. That URL is only for consumption by the web interface used to access Solr through a regular browser.

The direct URL to the core / collection is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/corename
```

.. but SolrJ uses (and is that's being shown in the example you linked) the URL without the core / collection name:

```
final String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl)
    .withConnectionTimeout(10000)
    .withSocketTimeout(60000)
    .build();
```

.. and then giving the core/collection name when adding:

```
final UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.add("techproducts", doc);
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to query but to index. So how can I adapt your solution?

Comment: You use `.add` instead of `.query`. This is literally the first thing shown on the tutorial you said you were following :-)